# Can the height of a UITableViewCell be changed without reloading the table view?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to resize a UITableViewCell without reloading the table view.

My UITableViewCell contains a UITextView so users can input list items that may be several lines (about four max) in length. Right now, I'm resizing the text view each time the user presses the return key, but I'd like to change the height of the table view cell *as well*.

The main problem I'm running into is that reloading the table view's data makes the text view lose focus. Is there any way to change the height of the UITableViewCell without reloading the table view, letting the user continue to input text in the text view?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To resize a table view row, try sending:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

These messages one immediately after the other should do the trick provided you have the correct height returned for that cell in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The row should animate.  You should be able to return the height of your cell using its bounds or just from knowing what you've set the cell height as.

Obviously "tableView" is the name of your table view.

Comment: That's great, thanks. There was also lots of help in [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015557/uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell-smooth-auto-resize-shows-and-hides-keyboard-on-ip) I found through the related articles on the sidebar, but somehow missed when searching before posting this.

Comment: Great tip! This helped a lot.

Comment: This works so easily. I was trying to animate the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for this easy Fix

Comment: This is really impressive! Thanks for sharing.