# Change height of UITextView in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: uitableview, height, uitextview

I'm trying to change the height of an UITextView which I have in a custom made Cell for my tableView.

The 'OverviewCell' is an identifier of this custom cell in a nib and also the UITextView 'postIntro' is dragged into the nib.

Sadly enough the height is not changing, only after i scrolled the height is changed. The cells which are visible without scrolling are just the default height from the nib.

When i try to change the height of the 'postImage' the same problem happens.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OverviewCell";

  OverviewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  if(!cell)
  {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverviewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[OverviewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (OverviewCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
  }

  [[cell postImage] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:post.image]];
  [[cell postTitle] setText:post.title];
  [[cell postIntro] setText:post.intro];

  // Resize the intro textview so the text fits in.
  CGRect frame = cell.postImage.frame;
  frame.size.height = 20; //cell.postIntro.contentSize.height;
  [cell.postIntro setFrame:frame];

  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Height of textView on indexpath %i is set to %f", indexPath.row ,cell.postImage.frame.size.height]);

  return cell;

}
```

Any other suggestions to my code is welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working by changing the constraint of the UITextview in code.

I've created and IBOutlet which is attached to the constraint of the UITextview.

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * postContentHeightConstraint;
```

After that I've set the constraint height to the specified height for the cell (`contentSize`).

```
self.postContentHeightConstraint.constant = self.postContent.contentSize.height;
```

After setting the new height to the constraint, call the layoutIfNeeded function on the UITextView

```
[self.postContent layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I had the same issue.  The way I fixed it was subclassing `UITableViewCell`, overriding the `drawRect:` method, and setting the height of the `UITextView` to `textView.contentSize.height`.  I already had the `UITableViewCell` subclass, but you could probably just subclass `UITextView` if that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) in your table view delegate.

**Update**: To update the height of the UITextView after it has been created, call `[cell.postIntro setNeedsLayout]` after setting the frame

Comment: This function is already there. That is adjusting the height of the cell which is working fine. I just want to change the height of the `UITextView` inside the cell (which is different in each cell)

Comment: Still not working, it's is only changed afters I scrolled down and back up again.

Comment: Is it possible it has something to do with the auto-layout and constraints of the uitextview?

Answer (score 0):

For changing the height of the `UITextView`, call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

after setting the new dimensions for the UITextView.

Questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792835/resizing-uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749746/uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell-smooth-auto-resize) will help with your problem.

Hope the answer helped!