# How to make a UITableView row grow dynamically with the user modified content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am asking this question already knowing the answer is "no you can't" but in the hopes someone has a brilliant idea here we go.

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell that has a few different subviews one of witch is a UITextField that I have as user editable. So naturally the textField grows with the text that is entered.

Now the question is how could I get the tableview row to grow with the textField.

I have a variety of different size cells so I know how to use `- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but the problem is that I need to modify the after the cell is already in the tableview.

Also note that the previously noted delegate method gets called before the data source delegate method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I have thought of just pulling up another view for the user to edit then putting that data into my data model then I would have to force the tableview to reload. (Can I reload just a certain cell/row)

Interestingly enough I think apple is doing what I want in their iTunes U app. When you tap a assignment it expands. I think they are using tableviews their right?

I know I have a lot of questions and talk here but I believe it is all related and just to show what I have researched. I am just looking for the possibility that one of you has a stroke of genius.

Hopefully this can help others also because this seems to be a hot topic but no one ask the question well or gets good answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this has been asked and answered many times -- it's not impossible. Search for "UITableView custom row height" or "UITableView multi line UITextField" or similar and you'll find several well-answered questions.

You're on the right track -- you need to return a height in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, even though that method is called before you create/configure the cell. This is okay... you just need a way to compute that height without having the cell. Other answers reference `-[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:]` and related methods... this should get you on the right track.

Changing the height while the text field is editing is less obvious, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3865350/957768) has the key... if you call

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

the table view will not only ask its delegate for `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` again and resize the cell to match, it'll do it with a smooth animation.