# How can I aesthetically resize a UITableview's Cell when I type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I'm trying to resize a UITableView's UITableViewCell as I type in a TextView in the cell. I want the text to keep flowing but focus on what I"m typing now. This is similar to what you would experience in the Mail App. What is the best way to resize the cell dynamically as I keep typing and entering content?

Comment: It might be easier (and more efficient) to just use a UITextView to enter the text.

Comment: @68cherries Yeah, he mentions he's using a text view, but I don't really understand why it's not sufficient for what he wants to achieve... Maybe I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: @Josh Wang I think it might be a bit of a distraction for the cell or the entire table view to resize as the user types.

Comment: Here are 3 great pieces of code from [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749746/uitextview-in-a-uitableviewcell-smooth-auto-resize).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are already sizing your cell dynamically.

Whenever the user types a character do this...

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: I do size my cell, and call begin and end updates, but it's a bit jerky. I guess what I'm asking for is how to make it a smooth transition like apple's mail app.

Comment: It's very smooth for me. Something else might be going on in your code.